# Heroku local serves only nodeJS and no angular and no connection to database

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, express, heroku

I seem to have two seperate problems. My app runs locally but not on heroku. If i try running "heroku local" it opens nodeJS app on localhost:5000 and it connects to local database. If i try to deploy it on heroku it build and install everything according to build log but doesn't run anything. Logs show production connection string(Heroku postgres) but I get error: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432. For angular I think i'm serving static pages wrong, but I can't figure it out. Thank you for any help.

app.js

```
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
require('./controllers/db')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var covidRouter = require('./routes/covid');
var trafficRouter = require('./routes/traffic');
var mobilityRouter = require('./routes/mobility');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build')));
console.log(__dirname)

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Total-Count');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, POST, PUT, GET');
    next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/covid', covidRouter);
app.use('/traffic', trafficRouter);
app.use('/mobility', mobilityRouter);


// const distFolder = isProduction?:'build';
app.use("/*",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'..','public','dist', 'index.html'));
});


// Obvladovanje napak zaradi avtentikacije
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name == "UnauthorizedError") {
        res.status(401).json({"sporocilo": err.name + ": " + err.message});
    }
});
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

module.exports = app;
```

db.js

```
const connectionString = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/postgres';
const connectionStringProd = 'dbConnectionStringHidden'
//(database = "postgres", user='postgres', password='postgres', host='127.0.0.1', port= '5432')

let isProduction = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
const pool = isProduction ? new Pool({connectionStringProd}) : new Pool({connectionString})


if (isProduction) {
  console.log("Prod")
  console.log(pool)
} else {
  console.log("Dev")
  console.log(pool)
}

async function query(query, params) {
    const {rows, fields} = await pool.query(query, params);

    return rows;
}

module.exports = {
  query
}
```

Heroku logs
[image]

Comment: You would need to have a database installed and running on the web server for this to work. I imagine in a looseley coupled cloud scenario, your database would be on a different host altogether, not 127.0.0.1

Comment: I have postgres base running on heroku and i can access it via pgAdmin. I also set it to connectionStringProd in db.js which is shown when i deploy it to heroku

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: Connection to Postgres is failing

-- You have setup a code to check for `let isProduction = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');`. Have you added this environment attribute to Heroku? If Heroku is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1:5432, then your env variable isn't set, else it should connect to your production database url specified in `dbConnectionStringHidden`. If you don't have any, then better get one, as there is no DB at Heroku's 127.0.0.1

Issue 2: Serving Angular's static files

As you are trying to serve your static files from **public/build** as specified in `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'build')));`, you should make sure that your angular build files are present in this folder. For this, you can either copy paste the built files there, or update the buildDir in angular.json to that folder.

Comment: Yes i have production string set. I've added picture of heroku logs where it is also printed. It's set yet it acts as if it want's to access local one

Comment: Also i've changed it to
```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist', 'public')));
```
But it still doesn't work.